# menu change after theme change

Tags: menus, themes

I changed theme for my wordpress site, and afterwards the menu got mixed. I added to more headings, and guess the failings came in there. Maybe I have tried to edit the wrong menu.
The content of two headings are the same as the third, even though if I go into the editing of pages, the content that should be there, is still there. 
I am not so good at wordpress

If anyone knows how to fix this, I would be very happy for a reply..! :-) 
With kindly regards, 
Karina

Comment: Are you talking about the Menu screen in Appearances -> Menu? If so, make sure you check the box that corresponds to your theme's menu. Sometimes when you change themes the box get's unchecked and a default menu (which consists of all items) will load in place.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is the problem you are having, but often when you switch themes, or rename the theme folder, the menu assignment box get's unchecked. If you go to Appearances -> Menu, select the menu that's not working from the dropdown. After clicking on "Select" make sure that the checkbox under "Display Location" is checked. In the example below, I created a menu called Util Nav, and assigned it to a menu I registered in the theme's function.php called "Utilities Nav". If no checkboxes are checked then wordpress will use a default menu instead.
[image]